# Executar um insert na tabela temporária no SQL SERver

Tags: sql-server

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo.

declare 
@ac varchar(max) = '(' + replace('2398,2399,2405,2407,2523,3509,3510,3518,3523,3524,3601,3859,4713,4728,4735,47362398,2399,2405,2407,2523,3509,3510,3518,3523,3524,3601,3859,4713,4728,4735,4736',',','),(') + ')'

select @ac

declare

@myList table (numero  bigint)

insert into @myList values @ac

select * from @myList

mas por algum motivo não esta indo já tentei um cast  oque poderia ser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
declare @ac varchar(max)
declare @myList table (ac varchar(max))
begin
    set @ac = '(' + replace('2398,2399,2405,2407,2523,3509,3510,3518,3523,3524,3601,'+
                         '3859,4713,4728,4735,47362398,2399,2405,2407,2523,3509,' +                        '3510,3518,3523,3524,3601,3859,4713,4728,4735,4736',',','),(') + ')'
    insert into @myList values ( @ac )
    select * from @myList
end
```